# Vertically centering :after block level elements

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to build this button with an :after data URI as the background (the arrow):
[image]

I need to vertically center the arrow. See my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BenRacicot/DL2MP/) On one line text it would be easy (with vertical-align) but when the lines break and wrap the arrow must still be centered. Since I cannot use extra tags thus I cannot use my usual trick of:

```
.container{position: relative;}
.innercontainer { 
    display: table; 
    position: absolute;
}
    .text p {
      display: table-cell; 
      vertical-align: middle; 
    }
```

Here is my actual HTML:

```
  <a class="btn" href="#">GLOBAL SOURCING AND SUPPLY CHAIN MANAGEMENT</a>
```

Here is my actual CSS

```
.btn{
  background-color: #bfd3ef;
  display: block;
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #a3c0e4!important;
  max-width: 300px;
  line-height: 22px;
  letter-spacing: .06em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;     background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAsAAAAWCAYAAAAW5GZjAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAKFJREFUeNpi/P//PwOxgBGbYsawZQegzAv/V0UVEFKMLLgQqCEBxGDCYeNFJHY8UPMCsCEMoUsNgDTIWn4CTl4IUvwAyJAnxoMgZwQA8Uci1C7E5cELQEof3ZO4PKiPLTRYcCg+SHQ4kxSDpCqGRzcQw53BAFKMBSODBTBxXIovYNMAkjAA4g//CYMFIDcTHd0kmUyym4kODZLCmaQYBAgwABskKz4QKS4hAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC);
    right: 28px;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the `top, left` positions a bit to get the desired outcome

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/johnbk/BLTHG/)

Comment: That actually isn't centered on single line text versions of the button. See fiddle

Comment: Included fiddle, Please check

Comment: Thanks John, but if you add a single line version its not centered vertically.

Comment: Please check the updated fiddle, I must say it is not absolutely centered, but close enough I think :)

Comment: Oh I see! 40% was the key. Great work and thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to center it vertically in your fiddle by adding

```
top: 50%;
```

to the styles for .btn:after.

Comment: Nice hopper but its not centered on single line versions.